# trying to redirect to www instead of without on Amazon S3 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect

Trying to redirect https://elementhcp.com to https://www.elementhcp.com I just want the www. to show up - all the files are being pulled in correctly it's just not adding the www. I've tried adding an .htaccess file and looked into the redirect on amazon which is setup correctly just not sure how to toggle or turn on the www. bit.

Not seeing the www. option in there not sure if I need to?

[image]

Here's what I have currently in place

[image]

Also have implemented this[image]

Comment: You can configure your DNS provider to redirect naked domain to www.

Comment: @hjpotter92 How do you go about that? I've been trying and can't figure it out. I've been editing the Route 53 but no dice.

Comment: @hjpotter92 please see my images above

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is actually:

- Host out of a bucket named `example.com` (not `www.example.com`)
- Create a `CNAME` record in Route 53 for `www.example.com` that points to `example.com`

However, if your bucket already exists as `www.example.com`, you could follow the instructions on [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html). It involves redirecting requests sent to `example.com` to `www.example.com`, similar to the pictures you've included in your question.

Comment: I'm also using Cloudfront not sure if that matters. I went through the tutorial you linked which was helpful in understanding but still didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Alias Target is not where you're *ultimately* redirecting.  It's the bucket that the browser is unitially requesting -- the bucket that is *generating* the redirect.

Select the web site endpoint bucket name (for the hostname without www) in the drop-down.   That's the correct answer.

Comment: It's not listed in the drop-down. ;( @Michael - sqlbot

Comment: Unless you photoshopped the screenshots @alcoven, it's listed under S3 Website Endpoints in the first image.

Comment: I'm using cloudfront though and when I select that the site loads nothing